# Finding all polynomials $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $P(n) \mid 2557^n + 213 \times 2014$ for all positive integers $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

This is a problem from the 2014 Thailand MO. Sadly I couldn't find the solution.

> Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that: $P(n) \mid 2557^n + 213 \times 2014$ for all positive integers $n$.

Edit: To summarize my efforts: I've tried replacing $n$ with some values but it didn't work. I then conjectured that $P(x) = \pm 1 $ are the only answers but was unable to prove it.

PS: This is my first time posting here so please forgive me if I make any mistakes.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Use [Shur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Number_theory) to get rid of the polynomials of positive degree. Note that if $q$ is a prime, then the remainder of $P((q-1)n)$ is the same as that of $P(-n)$ modulo $q$. So, if Shur allows you to find $n$ such that $P(-n)$ is divisible by a large prime $q$, then so will be $P((q-1)n)$. But $2557^{(q-1)n}=1$ modulo $q$. So, if $q$ is sufficiently large, it will not divide $1+213\cdot 2014$.

Comment: Yes, that conjecture is good. Once you exclude the polynomials of positive degree, as above, then you can, for example, compute the GCD of $2557^1+213\cdot 2014=431539$ and $2557^2+213\cdot 2014=6967231$. You will get that it is $1$. So, the only constant polynomials dividing both are $P(n)=\pm1$.

Comment: @plop I think I understand it now. Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=2557^x+213{\,\cdot\,}2014$, and suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $f(n){\,\mid\,}g(n)$ for all positive integers $n$.

**Claim:**$\;$Identically, either $f=1$ or $f=-1$.

**Proof:**

Suppose otherwise.

Then $|f(a)| > 1$ for some positive integer $a$.

Let $p$ be a prime factor of $f(a)$.

It's easily verified that $\gcd(2557,213)=1$ and $\gcd(2557,2014)=1$, hence since $f(a){\,\mid\,}g(a)$, we get $\gcd(p,2557)=1$.

From $p{\,\mid\,}f(a)$, it follows that $p{\,\mid\,}f(a+p)$.

Since $p$ is a common divisor of $f(a)$ and $f(a+p)$, $p$ is also a common divisor of $g(a)$ and $g(a+p)$, so
\begin{align*}
&
p{\,\mid\,}g(a+p)-g(a)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2557^{\large{a+p}}-2557^{\large{a}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2557^{\large{a}}\bigl(2557^{\large{p}}-1\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2557^p-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2557^{\large{p}}\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2557\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)&&\bigl(\text{by Fermat's little Theorem}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2556
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p\in\{2,3,71\}&&\bigl(\text{since $2556=2^2{\,\cdot\,}3^2{\,\cdot\,}71$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}\bigl(213{\,\cdot\,}2014\bigr)&&\bigl(\text{since $213=3{\,\cdot\,}71$ and $2014$ is even}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}\bigl(g(a)-(213{\,\cdot\,}2014)\bigr)&&\bigl(\text{since $p{\,\mid\,}g(a)$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2557^{\large{a}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p{\,\mid\,}2557
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.